# how do I copy armature with weights to another mesh?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, blend-files, weight-paint-mode

I saw some other posts on here with similar questions but nothing exactly like what I'm facing here. I'm trying to copy specific bones of the main body armature of a mesh to a clothing article in a separate blend file. I can get the armature over just fine but what I can't figure out for the life of me is figure out how to get the weights of the specific bones over to effect the clothing like it effects the model.

blend files : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TvJaDs_cEXMU4hrdep7HVxADmdGpXgJM?usp=sharing

The clothing model did have original armature but I deleted it because it was really bad (the devs didn't intend for people to rip the models from the game and use them for animation so I'm re rigging them)

I've only been using blender a few months so if you need other resources let me know.

Comment: You can't do that.  Weights are a property of _vertex groups_ and _vertex groups_ belong to _meshes_, not armatures.  For the weights to make sense the objects would have to have exactly the same messhes.

Comment: Addition to Marty's comment ... You can use Data Transfer modifier to transfer weights, but probably only one by one per group.

Answer (score 0):

I was told that it is impossible to do this exact thing so I found the quickest way around it. I selected the clothing and body model and did <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join the models and that gave the clothing model basic weights (so some weight painting is still required but thats pretty easy with paint masking), and it all seems to work perfectly.

I would recommend doing your texturing before you join the models (but you can always unjoin them later to do texturing)